# Apollo Server Doesn't Return Union Type As Expected

Tags: typescript, next.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

My resolver should return a union type, but no matter what it returns (either a `User` or an object with a `message` key and value of `String` type ie my `UserNotFoundError` type) it is always coming back with `"__typename": "User"`. Why is this and how do I correct it?

Resolver:

```
async validateUser(
      _: undefined,
      { email, password }: { email: string; password: string }
    ) {
      const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
          email,
        },
      });
      console.log('user before ', user);
      if (!user || user.password !== password) {
        const err = { message: 'Invalid user or password' };
        return err;
      }
      return user;
    },
```

typeDefs

```
 type User {
    email: String!
    password: String
    id: ID!
  }

  type UserNotFoundError {
    message: String!
  }

  union UserOrError = User | UserNotFoundError

  type Query {
    allUsers: [User!]!
    userByEmail(email: String!): User!
    validateUser(email: String!, password: String!): User
  }
```

result in Apollo Studio/Explorer, no matter what is actually returned by the resolver:

```
{
  "data": {
    "validateUser": {
      "__typename": "User"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated the rsolver defintion to `validateUser(email: String!, password: String!): UserOrError!` and now I get "Internal Server Error" in all cases

Answer (score 0):

the issue what that I wasn't setting `__typename` explicitly on the objects I returned.

This fixed it for me:

```
const err = {
  __typename: 'UserNotFoundError',
    message: 'Invalid user or password',
};

return err;
```

```
return {
  __typename: 'User',
  ...user,
};
```